# Telefonica Looking Glass?

Tags: bgp

Is there an openly accessible Looking Glass for Telefonica ?

None of the "official" URL's listed hereunder point to a functional Looking Glass server

http://www.telefonica-wholesale.com/es/herraIP.html  (from peeringdb.com)

http://lg.ri.telefonica-data.net/cgi-bin/lg.pl  (from bgp4.as/looking-glasses)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

Some ammunition for contacting their NOC:
http://www.internationalservices.telefonica.com/en/peerings.html

> Both parties shall provide access to a route server, looking glass, or
>   similar service for the purposes of routing audits, diagnostics, and
>   troubleshooting.

So seems reasonable to dedand access to one, considering they are demanding it.

Comment: maybe if you're a customer, but for joe internet user, don't put any money on it

Comment: good point - @user887 didn't indicate if he was a peer/customer of 12956... if he's neither, it's pretty likely that if he did contact the NOC, he might be waiting a while (forever) for a response.

Answer (score 1):

It's not appearing that way. You may want to redirect your query (either regarding the looking glass itself or the issues you're having that are prompting you to search for a looking glass) to the Telefonica NOC.